# Daily "Liver & <whatever>" commercial wet food?

Tags: cats, diet, feeding

I've seen this question, [Is it ok to feed my cat one chicken liver daily?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/33123/is-it-ok-to-feed-my-cat-one-chicken-liver-daily) and the answer was that "liver should be fed maybe once a week". However that question was about home-made food.

My question is about commercial wet foods, usually named like "Chicken & Liver", or "Liver & Turkey", etc. Liver is usually 2-4th ingredient there, but the food is formulated to be "balanced complete nutrition".

Is it OK to feed *that* food daily? Or is there risk of overdosing on the nutrients there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your location in the world, commercial pet food that is advertized as "complete" or "daily" nutrition must be safe to feed daily.

In the EU pet food is regulated by the European Food Safety Authority and must comply with several laws and regulations concerning the contents, labelling, testing of it's safety and marketing. In the US pet food is regulated by the FDA. In other parts of the worls pet food may be regulated by local authorities or not...

If a pet food that was manufactured in the US or EU claims that it's a "complete" food, fit to be fed "daily", then it must not contain any ingredient that can lead to an overdose or other adverse effect if a pet eats nothing but this food every day*. It must also contain all nutrients the pet needs to avoid malnutrition. Otherwise a feeding instruction must be written on the food container that informs the pet owner about how to balance the diet.

'* There have been discussions about pets getting diabetes or kidney problems for years now, but pet food manufacturers can avoid responsibility because the causation between pet food and such illnesses is not clear and objective enough.

There were (and probably will be) cases where certains brands of pet food lacked certain nutrients (like vitamins) or contained harmful substances (like mould), but these are exceptions.

*Please keep in mind that regulatory authorities cannot and do not test pet food in a lab. They rely on a mountain of documentation and the diligence of the manufacturer to ensure the safety of pet food. And they can issue warnings and ban products of there's a "notable incident", but that usually requires a few hundred pets dying an unnatural death that can be linked to the food somehow.*